# Finding $z(x,y)$ from $z(x,\text{constant})$ and $z(\text{constant},y)$

Tags: 3d, surfaces, regression, regression-analysis

I asked this question earlier, but I got no answer, maybe due to my bad English and bad explanation. Now, trying to ask in a different way, hope you can help me:

In a surface, the form of $z(x,y=\text{constant)}$ is known, say (For Example: $z=ax+b$, where $a$ and $b$ depend on the constant $y$).

Also, the form of $z(x=\text{constant},y)$ is known, say (For Example: $z=cy^2+d$, where $c$ and $d$ depend on the constant $x$).

How to find the from of $z(x,y)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are variables?

See the illustration:

[image]

For a fixed $y$, the relation between $x$ and $z$ is $z=ax+b$ (Green straight line).

And for a fixed $x$, the relation between $y$ and $z$ is $z=cy^2+d$ (Red parabola).

Is the form $z(x,y)=\sqrt{c_1x+c_2y^2+c_3xy+c_4}$? [This is not my actual problem].

---

My actual forms of $z(x,y=\text{constant})$ and $z(x=\text{constant},y)$ are much more complicated than a straight line and a parabola, but to make my problem easier to understand, I chose this example.

---

To summarize my problem; Knowing the form of $z(x,y=\text{constant})$ and the form of $z(x=\text{constant},y)$, how to find the form of $z(x,y)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are variables?

Any general/procedural way for any two known forms?

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: This is a really cool question. Not sure I can answer it, but I'm excited to see where it leads.

Comment: @K.defaoite hopefully one can answer this problem. I am trying since a year to solve it. Also, I posted it here before, but not yet solved. With full of hope, soon.

Comment: There could be more than one formula. For example, $ax+cy^2+b$ and $ax+cxy^2+b$ are both feasible. You need to know in addition how $a,b$ vary with $y$.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest form could be
$$z=c y^2+d \qquad \text{with} \qquad c=c_0+c_1x \quad \text{and}\quad d=d_0+d_1x$$ which would make
$$z=(c_1 y^2+d_1)x + (c_0 y^2+d_0)$$
$$z=(c_0+c_1x) y^2+(d_1x+d_0)$$

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for answering. But I have two points, hopefully you can explain: $1)$ form where you got $c=c_0+c_1x$ and $d=d_0+d_1x$? $2)$ I have much complicated forms, not a parabola and a straight line, I used that for example only, so is there a general way, so that I can solve my actual problem (which have different forms)? Thanks

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari. In a more general manner, say that you fit $z=f(y,c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n)$ at given $x$. Now the problem is to find the dependency of $c_k$ as a function of $x$.  Combine.